# Searching a website (including all child elements) for an image with unknown name

Tags: download, search, website, links, pictures

Problem: on a specific website, there's an image, somewhere... on the entire website. That image should link to a page with possibly a form in it.

For example, somewhere on superuser.com/ (and all pages included therein) there's a certain image. All I know is what that image would depict and that it would link to another page, and I know some possible keywords that could be contained in that page, or that could be in the name of the image.

How do I find this image? I've tried downloading the whole website with httrack, but it's taking forever. Is there another way?

Comment: Refining Google queries using operators should get you closer, no?

Comment: If you have a copy of the image you can do a reverse image search in Chrome

Comment: I don't have a copy of the image, google search doesn't work.